# "Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I was trying React Query and got this at the start of my React app.

[image: screenshot of the error: "Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one"]

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
    
const fetchPanets = async () => {
    const result = await fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people')
    return result.json()
    }
    
const Planets = () => {
    const { data, status } = useQuery('Planets', fetchPanets)
    console.log("data", data, "status", status)
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Planets</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
    
export default Planets
```

Comment: in 2022, this problem resurface once again but I dont know what is the correct version to make the problem go away :(

Comment: Make sure you're installing with `npm i @tanstack/react-query` for v4+.

Answer (score 91):

As the error suggests, you need to wrap your application in a `QueryClientProvider`. This is on the first page of the [docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/overview):

```js
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, useQuery } from 'react-query'

const queryClient = new QueryClient()

export default function App() {
   return (
     <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
       <Example />
     </QueryClientProvider>
   )
}
```

Comment: I use package "react-query" first then I realize there is a newer version "@tanstack/react-query". So after a while a realize I use the provider from the newer version but consumer code was using "useMutation" from the old package. That's why it cannot not find the Provider for my old code.

Comment: passive agressive much?

Answer (score 40):

While this is most commonly caused by not having your application wrapped in a `<QueryClientProvider>`, in my case it happened because I was importing some shared components, which ended up with a different context. You can fix this by setting the `contextSharing` option to `true`

That would look like:

```
 import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query'
 
 const queryClient = new QueryClient()
 
 function App() {
   return <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient} contextSharing={true}>...</QueryClientProvider>
 }
```

From the docs: (https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/QueryClientProvider)

`contextSharing`: boolean (defaults to false)

Set this to true to enable context sharing, which will share the first and at least one instance of the context across the window to ensure that if React Query is used across different bundles or microfrontends they will all use the same instance of context, regardless of module scoping.

Comment: doesn't always work idk why

Comment: The contextSharing option has been deprecated and will be removed in the next major version

Comment: @azu did you find a solution that works with v4? I am facing the same issue and context sharing doesn't seem like a solution.

Answer (score 28):

In my case I was importtng from 'react-query' in one place and '@tanstack/react-query' in another.

Comment: Yep I did the same thing

Comment: Same problem here. Change all of them and it works fine

Comment: I did the same thing too; I changed it to:

```import {
  useMutation
} from "@tanstack/react-query";
```

And then, everything worked well.

Answer (score 15):

Just make changes like below it will work fine

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
const queryClient = new QueryClient();

ReactDOM.render(
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <App />
  </QueryClientProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 8):

I got that error when trying to add the react-query **devtools**.

The problem was I was installing it wrongly according my version, I was using react-query v3.

**WRONG FOR react-query V3 (GOOD FOR V4)**

```
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from '@tanstack/react-query-devtools';
```

**OK FOR react-query V3**

```
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from 'react-query/devtools';
```

Comment: This was me. I don't know how you found this but fair play.

Answer (score 5):

```
import {  QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, useQuery } from 'react-query';
const queryClient = new QueryClient();
const fetchPanets = async () => {
    const result = await fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people')
    return result.json()
}

const Planets = () => {
    const { data, status } = useQuery('Planets', fetchPanets)
    console.log("data", data, "status", status)
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Planets</h2>
        </div>
    );
}


export default function Wraped(){
return(<QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <Planets/>
    </QueryClientProvider>
);
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this one mate. the Wrapped type was the missing piece for me.

Answer (score 3):

**Single SPA (micro-frontend) - React Query v3.34.15**

I was getting this error while trying to integrate a sigle-spa react parcel into the root application.

I used `craco-plugin-single-spa-application` for the building of a CRA app as a way to adapt it for a parcel. In the **entry** config I was pointing to my `single-spa-react` config.

```html
// craco.config.js

const singleSpaApplicationPlugin = require('craco-plugin-single-spa-application')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: singleSpaApplicationPlugin,
      options: {
        orgName: 'uh-platform',
        projectName: 'hosting',
        entry: 'src/config/single-spa-index.cf.js',
        orgPackagesAsExternal: false,
        reactPackagesAsExternal: true,
        externals: [],
        minimize: false 
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In the `single-spa-index.cf.js` file I had the following configs.

```html
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import singleSpaReact from 'single-spa-react'

import App from '../App'

const lifecycles = singleSpaReact({
  React,
  ReactDOM,
  rootComponent: App,
  errorBoundary() {
    return <div>Ocorreu um erro desconhecido!</div>
  }
})

export const { bootstrap, mount, unmount } = lifecycles
```

After reading a bunch of forums and the react-query documentation, the only thing that I figured out I needed to change was pass in the `QueryClientProvider` the prop `contextSharing` as true. After had did this change, ran the building and access the route that opens my parcel. I got the same error.

```html
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query'
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from 'react-query/devtools'

import App from './App'

const queryClient = new QueryClient()

const isDevelopmentEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'

if (isDevelopmentEnv) {
  import('./config/msw/worker').then(({ worker }) => worker.start())
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <QueryClientProvider contextSharing={true} client={queryClient}>
      <App />
      {isDevelopmentEnv && <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />}
    </QueryClientProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

But, how do I solved that. Well, it was was simple. I couldn't even imagine why it was working locally. But not after building and integration.

The problem was because I put the React Query Provider inside the index o the application and in my `single-spa-index.cf.js` I was importing `import App from '../App'` which really wasn't wrapped by the provider. Once I also was importing **App** in the application index, where It was wrapped making It works locally.

So after figure that out, my code was like that:
**CODE AFTER SOLUTION**

```html
// craco.config.js
const singleSpaApplicationPlugin = require('craco-plugin-single-spa-application')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: singleSpaApplicationPlugin,
      options: {
        orgName: 'uh-platform',
        projectName: 'hosting',
        entry: 'src/config/single-spa-index.cf.js', 
        orgPackagesAsExternal: false,
        reactPackagesAsExternal: true,
        externals: [], 
        minimize: false 
      }
    }
  ]
}

// src/config/single-spa-index.cf.js 
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import singleSpaReact from 'single-spa-react'

import App from '../App'

const lifecycles = singleSpaReact({
  React,
  ReactDOM,
  rootComponent: App,
  errorBoundary() {
    return <div>Ocorreu um erro desconhecido!</div>
  }
})

export const { bootstrap, mount, unmount } = lifecycles


// App.tsx
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query'
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from 'react-query/devtools'

import { config } from 'config/react-query'
import Routes from 'routes'
import GlobalStyles from 'styles/global'

import * as S from './styles/shared'

const queryClient = new QueryClient(config)

const isDevelopmentEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'

if (isDevelopmentEnv) {
  import('./config/msw/worker').then(({ worker }) => worker.start())
}

function App() {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider contextSharing={true} client={queryClient}>
      <S.PanelWrapper>
        <Routes />
        <GlobalStyles />
      </S.PanelWrapper>

      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  )
}

export default App

// index.tsx
import { StrictMode } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import App from './App'

ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Well, it was long but I hope it helps someone that's undergoing for the same problem as mine.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I accidentally used two different versions of react-query in my modules.

Answer (score 3):

Just be careful when upgrade from `react-query v3` to `@tanstack/react-query v4`.

Ensure that you replace all imports as **"react-query"** to **"@tanstack/react-query"** and then run `yarn remove` *the lib that you won't use anymore*, otherwise you may accidentally import the unexpected one.
This happened to me and caused this error.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to fix the same thing:

I followed the [React Query docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/overview)
and used the concept of [Higher Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

See if it helps:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, useQuery } from 'react-query';

import Planet from './Planet';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const fetchPlanets = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('http://swapi.dev/api/planets/');
    return res.json();
}

const Planets = () => {

    const { data, status } = useQuery('planets', fetchPlanets);

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Planets</h2>
            { status === 'loading' && (<div>Loading data...</div>)}
            { status === 'error' && (<div>Error fetching data</div>)}
            {
                status === 'success' && (
                    data.results.map(planet =>
                        <Planet
                            key={planet.name}
                            planet={planet}
                        />
                    )
                )
            }
        </div>
    )
}

// Higher order function
const hof = (WrappedComponent) => {
    // Its job is to return a react component warpping the baby component
    return (props) => (
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            <WrappedComponent {...props} />
        </QueryClientProvider>
    );
};

export default hof(Planets);
```

Comment: Awesome work! This is a great pattern to follow for `useQuery `

Answer (score 1):

For me it's caused by **react-query devtools**

- "react-query": "^3.39.3"
- "react-query-devtools": "^2.6.3"

and importing like this:

- import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
- import { ReactQueryDevtools } from 'react-query/devtools';

So, the **solution** is change the version using:

- "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.13.0",
- "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.13.0",

and import like this:

- import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
- import { ReactQueryDevtools } from '@tanstack/react-query-devtools';

Answer (score 0):

In my case

Error `import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";`

Solution `import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";`

remove it `@tanstack/`

Answer (score 0):

> I have faced a similiar issue and I fixed by upgrading the package

```
npm i @tanstack/react-query@beta
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case I was trying to access the user from react query cache in my `<App />` component before registering the `<QueryClientProvider>`.

```js
function App() {
  const { user } = useCurrentUser();

  console.log({ user });

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes />
      <Loading />
      <Toaster />
      <ReactQueryDevtools />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use useQuery inside the same functional component where you are using QueryClientProvider. thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!