# Next.js build error, Error occurred prerendering page "/"

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-query

I'm using Next.js and React-query to implement a useUser Hook for page processing through user authentication.

I have implemented useUser Hook normally and it runs fine in develop.

However, when building through `npm run build`, the following error occurs and an error occurs in the build.

> Error occurred prerendering page "/login". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
> Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one
> at Object.useQueryClient

I guess react-query throws an error, but I don't know how to fix it.

how do i solve it??

```js
///useUser.tsx
const useUser = ({ redirectTo, redirectIfFound }: IParams) => {
  const { data, error } = useQuery(["authed"], isAuthed);
  const [calledPush, setCalledPush] = useState(false);

  const user = data?.data;  //Returns true if the user is authenticated, false otherwise
  const hasUser = user;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!redirectTo) return;
    if ((redirectTo && !redirectIfFound && !hasUser) || (redirectIfFound && hasUser)) {
      let calledPushLatest;
      setCalledPush((latest) => {
        calledPushLatest = latest;
        return latest;
      });

      if (calledPushLatest) return; // router.push has already been called

      // proceed to redirect
      setCalledPush(true);
      Router.push(redirectTo);
    }
  }, [redirectTo, redirectIfFound, hasUser]);

  return error ? null : user;
};
```

```js
//index.tsx
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  // const user = useUser({ redirectTo: "/login" });

  // if (user === undefined || user === false) {
  //   return <div>Loading...</div>;
  // }

 //^ If I uncomment this part, the above error occurs.
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Our-Survey</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <div>Home</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is my package.json dependency.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.0.10",
    "@types/recoil": "^0.0.9",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "next": "12.2.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.1",
    "recoil": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/node": "18.0.6",
    "@types/react": "18.0.15",
    "@types/react-query": "^1.2.9",
    "babel-jest": "^28.1.3",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  }
```

How do I solve it to make it build normally?

Comment: Are you using `QueryClientProvider` anywhere?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65590195/no-queryclient-set-use-queryclientprovider-to-set-one)?